# Creating Two Scanners In Different Class

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am currently using two different scanners in my project in two separate classes: both take in user input that do different things. Calling the first scanner works normally, but when I try to call the second scanner, even after I've closed the first, it registers the input as null.

Class 1

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
public void foobar(){
    System.out.println("Enter data: ");
    String foo = scan.next();
    scan.close();
    class2.function(foo);
}
```

Class 2

```
Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
public void foobar1(String foo){
    System.out.println("Enter more data: ");
    String fooo = scan1.Next();
    //Automatically prints null here and closes program
}
```

Am I supposed to only use one Scanner somehow? Or do I use the Scanner class in some other manner? Thanks!

Comment: can you please tell me why you need this?

Comment: maybe create a class that has your scanner and let the other classes extend this class?

Comment: use `scan.reset();` instead of `scan.close();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scan.close();` also closes `System.in` so that no more data can be read from the stream. So when you start reading from `scan1`, `System.in` will no longer return any data.

Therefore, don't close any `Scanner` instance until you're done with all the scanning if you're using the same input stream for all the instances.

Look at the docs of [`Scanner#close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close%28%29) for more info.

> Closes this scanner. **If this scanner has not yet been closed then if its underlying readable also implements the Closeable interface then the readable's close method will be invoked.**

And if you look at the docs of [`System.in`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html), you can see that it does implement the `Closeable` interface.

Thus the [`InputStream#close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#close%28%29) is called and that closes the `InputStream` leaving you without a input stream to read data from.

> Closes this input stream and releases any system resources associated with the stream.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 1):

No need to create two scanners, You can use same `Scanner` for both as once scan is closed Stream `System.in` also get closed.
like:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
public void foobar(){
    System.out.println("Enter data: ");
    String foo = scan.next();
    class2.function(foo,scan);
}
```

where:

```
public void function(String foo,Scanner scan1){
    System.out.println("Enter more data: ");
    String fooo = scan1.next();
    System.out.println(fooo);
}
```

but still if you need to create two scanners use `scan.reset();` instead of `scan.close();` in class1

Comment: This also makes a lot of sense! Thanks! I will definitely use this next time.